# Conditional Weighted Average

Tags: r, dataframe, weighted-average

I'm looking to build out a conditional weighted average formula.

| Loan Amount | Loan Term | Credit Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71100 | 75 | 636 |
| 29190 | 75 | 803 |
| 16865.89 | 72 | 569 |
| 22930.86 | 75 | 556 |
| 11663.19 | 72 | 531 |

In R, how would you get the loan term's weighted average by loan amount for credit scores between 500-600?

The output should equal 73.34 and in excel would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(C2:C6>500),1*(C2:C6<600),A2:A6,B2:B6)/SUMPRODUCT(1*(C2:C6>500),1*(C2:C6<600),A2:A6)
```

Comment: ```with(subset(df1, Credit_Score > 500, Credit_Score < 600), sum(Loan_Amount * Loan_Term) / sum(Loan_Amount))```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you can do this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(Credit_Score < 600 & Credit_Score > 500) %>% 
  summarise(Weighted_Average = sum(Loan_Amount * Loan_Term) / sum(Loan_Amount))
#>   Weighted_Average
#> 1         73.33682
```

***Data:***

```
read.table(text="Loan_Amount    Loan_Term   Credit_Score
71100   75  636
29190   75  803
16865.89    72  569
22930.86    75  556
11663.19    72  531", header=T) -> df1
```